# How to restart serenity scenario at failure and get success in the report in case of success result

Tags: java, junit, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to add a method in order to avoid the false positives from the jenkins run.

So i have many tests which are running in Jenkins and some of them are randomly failing and i want to find a way to tell the runner to restart that particular scenario and in case of success to update the report/result

I found something about: RestartingScenarioFailure but is not really working as i want, i mean its throwing me an exception, which i dont want.

I'm using serenity with JBehave and Junit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max.retries=1
junit.retry.tests=true

This is a quick solution... not the best but at least is out of the box, you just need this two lines inside the serenity.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven take a look at Maven Failsafe plugin Rerun Failing Tests feature:

[http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.htmlhttp://)

Comment: The page does not load but i'm using gradle i believe i can adapt it in case you can provide a valid page

Comment: Ckeck the plugin website. Not sure why the above link does not work. http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html